# Subtract fields in the same column to get interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table "@table1" and I would like recursively update on the"Amount" column from the BOTTOM to the TOP ordering by RowID. That is taking the negative values subtracting that value with value of row above, if the end result is still a negative subtract that value with the next row, replacing the previous value with 0.

```
 DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int, Amount int);
    INSERT @table1 VALUES 
    (1,20),
    (2,10),
    (3,-10),
    (4,10),
    (5,-5),
    (6,30);
Select * from @table1


RowID       Amount
----------- -----------
1           20
2           10
3           -10
4           10
5           -5
6           30
```

Results Table

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int, Amount int);
    INSERT @table1 VALUES 
    (1,20),
    (2,0),
    (3,0),
    (4,5),
    (5,0),
    (6,30); 
Select * from @table1


RowID       Amount
----------- -----------
1           20
2           0
3           0
4           5
5           0
6           30
```

Comment: What single value 110? Why is 50 subtracted from 60, 0 ignored, and 12 and 34 left the same? What do negative values have to do with anything (I don't see any negative values here)? This question is unclear and I think you've left out some information.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - not really sure why anyone would want to do this, but the requirement seems to be:  starting with the last record, subtract 110 or the ProductCount for the row, whichever is greatest (i.e.) do not go into negative values.  Update the number to subtract, and repeat until there is nothing left to subtract.

Comment: @KipReal: The question is unclear. Please add supplementary informations if you want to get good answers. I didn't vote it down.

Comment: @Daniel that may be true, but we still need a lot more information. How do we identify 10 as the "last" row and therefore starting point? How do we move to 60 as the "next" row?

Comment: @Kip while again, for the record, I didn't down-vote, I think you have it backwards. Rather than discouraging people from asking questions, it *EN* courages people to ask more complete questions. More complete questions are better for everyone.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I totally agree, the question should definitely contain more info.  I was answering your specific questions around why the result set looked the way it did (which was - barely - deducable from the question) :)

Comment: After reading the comments, I still don't understand what the OP wants and how the results go from A to B. The sentence 'The single value 110 the results on the column should be', which is essential in determining the requirement, doesn't even make grammatical sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of implementing this (as a single query) would be to use something like a [running total](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-running-totals.html) .  This effectively ends up joining the Product table on itself in such a way that for each row in the "left" table, the "right" table contains all records that "come before it".  This way, you could keep a running total of your updated field.  Unfortunately it's quite confusing to write and performs atrociously.

Depending on your intended usage scenarios, this might be one of those rare cases where cursors are the better alternative.  Writing one using cursors and table variables should be relatively trivial.